# How to Create an Alumni Association in India

Tags: india, regulations, non-profit

I have a group of ex-students who want to form an alumni association in **india**. What is the legal process for this?  E.g., where and how do we register?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose of the organization. An applicable law seems to be the [Societies Registration Act, 1860](http://www.mca.gov.in/Ministry/actsbills/pdf/Societies_Registration_Act_1860.pdf) which says

> Any seven or more persons associated for any literary, scientific, or
>   charitable purpose, or for any such purpose as is described in section
>   20 of this Act, may, by subscribing their names to a memorandum of
>   association, and filing the same with Registrar of Joint-stock
>   Companies form themselves into a society under this Act.

Section 20 then adds the list

> Charitable societies, the military orphan funds or societies
>   established at the several presidencies of India, societies
>   established for the promotion of science, literature, or the fine arts
>   for instruction, the diffusion of useful knowledge, [the diffusion of
>   political education], the foundation or maintenance of libraries or
>   reading-rooms for general use among the members or open to the public
>   or public museums and galleries of paintings and other works of art,
>   collections of natural history, mechanical and philosophical
>   inventions, instruments, or designs.

It does not seem that an alumni association can straightforwardly be registered as a society. However, it appears that "Society" is a term of art connected with tax exemption. And since you didn't use the word "society", I assume you are not looking for the tax benefit. In that case, the Constitution [Article 19](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_India/Part_III#Article_19_.7BProtection_of_certain_rights_regarding_freedom_of_speech.2C_etc..7D) 1(a) says that "All citizens shall have the right to form associations or unions; or co-operative societies", which implies that no registration is required.

Comment: Good for knowledge . But i don't want to become a loyar. So what is the process of same. And tnks for info it is usefull ;)

Comment: I think registration is requied. Bucouse my b.tech college has register alum. Assoc.